# Apple Trees: Grafting multiple scions to new rootstock

Tags: roots, apples, grafting, crabapples

I've gotten bitten by the apple grafting bug, and after some initial successes have placed an order for around 20 scions or different varieties, and around 15 MM102 rootstocks (thickness unknown, the nursery doesn't list the details, and I've not heard back from them yet after making an inquiry), this was the most I could get my hands on of MM102, which is pretty much the most suitable for my region/yard size/pests and diseases resistance/etc, whilst still being available here in Australia (Bud. group rootstocks aren't very common here, and Geneva group rootstocks are commercial stock only).

My question is: due to having more scions than rootstocks, will there be any major issues with grafting 2 scions to a few of the rootstocks?
i.e. slower in plant growth, weaker graft union sites, higher risk of graft failure, etc.

And a secondary question of: If it's perfectly ok to graft multiple in one step, what graft type and positioning should I use? (both at top with whip and tongue? one whip and tongue at top, and  aside veneer lower down? two side veneer grafts? Skip the standard grafts and go straight to bug grafting?)

Looking around it seems that it's not common to see 1 step multi-scion grafting on fresh rootstock, so my info is scarce and my concerns are high.

Don't hesitate to ask me for more info!

Comment: One problem that you did not mention is that, over a number of years, one scion is likely to become dominant among the two grafted on the same rootstock - almost defying the purpose of multiple grafts.

Comment: That's a good point to make, for sure, although my advise has been that it'll take quite a while to do so, and by selective cutting and notching that can be handled reasonably well. And a little off the real topic, but I'll be likely culling breeds that don't taste/perform well, anyway, haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely possible, though as Alex Alex stated it is very likely one graft will become dominant in the long run. My suggestion to combat this would be to plan and prune them to try and keep them loosely the same size (once healthy enough of course)

And as far as getting multiple to take, that is highly dependent on the size of the rootstock you're working with. Though if there is enough room, in my experience, your success rate should barely change. The smaller they are though the herder it will be of course and that can definitely affect % success